# React typescript app how to stop logouts in refresh?

Tags: reactjs

I am working in a react app built with typescript which takes Django api for log in. I am storing the json web token in my local storage. But the app still logs out automatically when I refresh the page.
Here is what I have done

Django urls.py

```
    path('login/', obtain_jwt_token),
```

This api is called in react logInContainer. I am saving the token in my local storage.

```
const logInContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const api = new Api();
  const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  const [errorText, setError] = React.useState('');

  const signIn = async () => {
    const res = await api.post('/login/', {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    });
    const json = JSON.stringify(res);
    localStorage.setItem("user-info", json);
    if (res) {
      dispatch(logInAction(res.token));
    } else {
      setError('login failed');
    }
  }
```

My logInAction

```
export const LogInAction = (token: string): AuthTypes => {
  return {
    type: AuthTypes.logIn,
    payload: {
      token: token,
    }
  };
};
```

My authTypes.ts

```
export const AuthTypes= {
  logIn: "SIGN_IN",
  logOut: "SIGN_OUT",
} as const;
```

So far, the login works fine. and the token is also stored in local storage. But whenever I refresh my page, the app log outs automatically. I need to solve this issue. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Here is how logout happens

```
  const logOut = async () => {
    
    dispatch(logOutAction())
  };
```

This is called by

```
<IconButton onClick={logOut}>
    <ExitToApp />
</IconButton>
```

here is logOutAction

```
export const logOutAction = (): AuthTypes => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.logOut,
  };
};
```

In my reducer ts

```
import { AuthState, AuthTypes } from "./types";
const initialState: AuthState = {
  token: '',
  isSignIn: false,
};
```

Which goes to authTypes

```
case ActionTypes.signIn:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload, { isSignIn: true });
```

Comment: The given code is not sufficient to find out where the logout happens. Please add more info so that I can help you

Comment: @Ajith wait a minute. I am adding it.

Comment: Please check how you validate login on each routes, Are you using store for storing login user info along with your localstorage?

Comment: @Ajith check now

Comment: Writing to local storage is the first step, but on page load it needs to read from local storage to see if there is a previously saved user info.

Comment: What  you have witten on other secure routes( Routes that require login) Also In login route you can check if localstorage already exists, then you can redirect to other pages like dashboard , profile page etc

Comment: You have to read the jwt from localStorage first in your starter component. And check if there is a token and it's valid. If there is a token and it's valid, redirect to your home page/dashboard. If not redirect to login to component.

Comment: @Ajith I am using auth.isSignIn to show components that logged in users should see. If auth.isSignIn is false, I am redirecting to login page

Comment: What is written in auth.isSignIn function ?

Comment: @Ajith check now

Comment: @AJcodez once user logs in I am setting isSign to true

Comment: @mage456 Could you please check my answer and let me know . In your code token is always set to null on refresh, I have modified that part and check if the token exist in localstorage, I ll assign that value else will set it to null

Comment: @Ajith please check my comment to your answer. I get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try to change your reducer code as given below

```
import { AuthState, AuthTypes } from "./types";
const initialState: AuthState = {
  token    : localStorage.getItem('token')? localStorage.getItem('token') : '',
  isSignIn : localStorage.getItem('token')? true : false,
};
```

Comment: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
I get this error. I am using typescript

Comment: I want to see your locastorage value after login  `localStorage.getItem('token')` , Use correct variable name, You can follow the logic and apply to your code